# SQLAlchemy searching with multiple unkown variables

Tags: python-2.7, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a database with age, salary, department & state.  I want to be able to search with any of these variables some given some are skipped.

I know i can do something like this:

```
kwargs = { 'age':'21', 'salary':'65000','departmentid':'3,5' }
s.query.filter_by(**kwargs)
```

However, I need something like age > 21, salary > 45000 and salary < 75000, departmentid in (3,5) and skip state altogether.

How can i achieve this without without writing 500 lines of code?

I am using python 2.7, sqlalchemy and mysql.